# Расчет итогового значения по нескольким параметрам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Создаю калькулятор. После блока *"Перила"* необходимо, чтобы складывались значения, а они умножаются. В чем ошибка?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Заменяем кнопку <button>рассчитать стоимость</button> на <span class="cur"></span>, в который будет подставляться рассчитанная сумма
    $('.price-button').click(function () {
        var boxPrice = $(this).closest('.price-inner');
        function hideButton() {
            $(boxPrice).find('.price-button').hide();
            $(boxPrice).find('.footer-price').append('<h4>Итог: <span class="cur"></span> <span class="rub">р. / м.погонный.</span></h4>');
        };
        //анимация раскрытия блока с параметрами
        $(boxPrice).find('.box-price').animate({
            height: '1800px'
        }, {
            'duration': 500
        }, {
            'easing': 'linear'
        }, hideButton());
    });
    //отслеживаем выделение параметра, чтобы в блоке был только 1 выделенный элемент
    $('ul.parametrs li').click(function () {
        var listParam = $(this).closest('ul.parametrs');
        $(listParam).find('li.check-param').removeClass('check-param');
        var elemParam = $(this);
        $(elemParam).addClass('check-param');

        var elemAttr = $(elemParam).attr('data-param');
    });
    ////////////Калькулятор
    //получаем значения параметров
    function valParam() {
        var Price = $('.box-filter').attr('data-price'); //получаем стоимость погонных метров.
        var paramValuePoroda = $('#poroda').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param');
        var roofValue = $('#roof').val(); //вычисляем длину лестницы
        var paramValueMarch = $('#heightMarch').val(); //вычисляем ширину марша
        var paramValueNumberSteps = $('#humberSteps').val(); //вычисляем Общее количество ступеней
        var paramValueRailing = $('#railing').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param'); // Перила
        var paramValueTypeStairs = $('#typeStairs').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param'); // Тип лестницы
        var paramValueTypeTurn = $('#typeTurn').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param'); // Тип поворота
        var paramValueTypeStage = $('#typeStage').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param'); // пригласительная ступень
        var paramValuePodstupenniki = $('#podstupenniki').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param'); // Подступенники
        var paramValuePainting = $('#painting').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param'); // покраска
        var paramValueMounting = $('#mounting').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param'); // монтаж
        if ($.isNumeric(roofValue)) {
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValuePoroda)) paramValuePoroda = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(roofValue))
                roofValue = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueMarch))
                paramValueMarch = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueNumberSteps))
                paramValueNumberSteps = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueRailing))
                paramValueRailing = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueTypeStairs))
                paramValueTypeStairs = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueTypeTurn))
                paramValueTypeTurn = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueTypeStage))
                paramValueTypeStage = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValuePodstupenniki))
                paramValuePodstupenniki = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValuePainting))
                paramValuePainting = 1;
            if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueMounting))
                paramValueMounting = 1;
            var total = Price * paramValuePoroda * roofValue * paramValueMarch * paramValueNumberSteps * paramValueRailing * paramValueTypeStairs * paramValueTypeTurn * paramValueTypeStage * paramValuePodstupenniki * paramValuePainting * paramValueMounting; //формула расчета общей стоимости
            var newTotal = Math.round(total);
            $('.cur').html(newTotal);
            $('.rub').show();
        };
    };
    //отслеживаем изменение данных
    $('.calculator').on('click keyup', valParam);
})
```

```css
.container-cal {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
.name-price {
    background: #4169E1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.name-price h3 {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box-price {
    background: #DDDDDD;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
}
.box-filter {
    padding: 0px 0;
}
.form-group {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.form-group label {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul.parametrs {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.parametrs li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.parametrs > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
ul.parametrs .check-param {
    background-color: #f00;
    color: #FFF;
}
.footer-price {
    background: #2E8B57;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 25px 0;
}
input[type="text"], select {
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.price-button {
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF !important;
    font-size: .875em;
    color: #cacaca;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    outline: 0;
}
.price-button:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #fff;
    color: #333!important;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.cur {
    font-size: 36px;
}
.rub {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-cal">   
           
            <div class="price">               
    <div class="price-inner">
                    <div class="calculator">
                        <div class="name-price">
       <h3>Калькулятор расчета стоимости услуг</h3>
      </div>
                        <div class="box-price">
                            <div class="box-filter" data-price="3000">
                                
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Порода дерева</label>
                                    <ul class="parametrs" id="poroda">
                                        <li class="label check-param" data-param="1">сосна</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1.636666666666667">лиственница</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="2.546">бук</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="3.4553333333333333333333333333333333">дуб</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="roof">Длина лестницы (В метрах погонных:)</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                       <input type="text" name="roof" class="form-control" id="roof" value="" placeholder="0">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Ширина марша</label>
                                    <div class="row">
          <select  id="heightMarch"  name="march">
           <option selected>Ширина марша<option>
           <option value="1.9">0.9<option>
           <option value="2.2">1<option>
           <option value="2.5">1.1<option>
           <option value="2.8">1.2<option>
           <option value="3.1">1.3<option>
           <option value="3.4">1.4<option>
           <option value="3.7">1.5<option>
           <option value="4">1.6<option>
           <option value="4.3">1.7<option>
           <option value="4.7">1.8<option>
           <option value="5">1.9<option>
           <option value="5.3">2<option>
          </select>          
                                    </div>
                                </div>        
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Общее количество ступеней</label>
                                    <div class="row">                                                
           
           <select id="humberSteps"  name="steps">
            <option selected>количество ступеней<option>
            <option value="1">5<option>
            <option value="1.1">6<option>
            <option value="1.2">7<option>
            <option value="1.3">8<option>
            <option value="1.4">9<option>
            <option value="1.5">10<option>
            <option value="1.6">11<option>
            <option value="1.7">12<option>
            <option value="1.8">13<option>
            <option value="1.9">14<option>
            <option value="2">15<option>
            <option value="2.1">16<option>
            
            <option value="2.2">17<option>
            <option value="2.3">18<option>
            <option value="2.4">19<option>
            <option value="2.5">20<option>
            <option value="2.6">21<option>
            <option value="2.7">22<option>
            <option value="2.8">23<option>
            <option value="2.9">24<option>
            <option value="3">25<option>
            <option value="3.1">26<option>
            <option value="3.2">27<option>
            <option value="3.3">28<option>
            
            <option value="3.4">29<option>
            <option value="3.5">30<option>
            <option value="3.6">31<option>
            <option value="3.7">32<option>
            <option value="3.8">33<option>
            <option value="3.9">34<option>
            <option value="4">35<option>
            <option value="4.1">36<option>
            <option value="4.2">37<option>
            <option value="4.3">38<option>
            <option value="4.4">39<option>
            <option value="4.5">40<option>
           </select>
         </div> 
                                </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Перила</label>
                                    <ul class="parametrs" id="railing">
                                        <li class="label" data-param="2.08">по внутренне стороне</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="3.16">по двум сторонам</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Тип лестницы</label>
                                    <ul class="parametrs" id="typeStairs">
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1.41">на 90 градусов</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1.5466666666666667">на 180 градусов</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Тип поворота</label>
                                    <ul class="parametrs" id="typeTurn">
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1.3">площадка</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1.45">забежные ступени</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
        
        <h2>Дополнительные параметры</h2>
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>пригласительная ступень</label>
                                    <ul class="parametrs" id="typeStage">
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1">нет</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1.183333333333333333333333333333333333333333">да</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>     
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Подступенники</label>
                                    <ul class="parametrs" id="podstupenniki">
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1">нет</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1.533333333333333333333333333333333333333333">да</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>покраска</label>
                                    <ul class="parametrs" id="painting">
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1">без покраски</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="12.66666666666667">покраска в цвет с лаком</li>
          <li class="label" data-param="11">покраска бесцветным лаком</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>монтаж</label>
                                    <ul class="parametrs" id="mounting">
                                        <li class="label" data-param="1">нет</li>
                                        <li class="label" data-param="4.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333">да</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>  
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer-price">
                            <button type="button" class="price-button">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kypn2f9t/).

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что далеко не весь представленный в вопросе код имеет отношение к проблеме. Почему вы не решили выбрать только действительно важный участок и создать **минимальный** пример, необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы? Вполне может быть, что во время создания такого примера вы бы поняли в чем проблема, и вопрос бы вообще не пришлось создавать.

Comment: По повода самого вопроса: я вижу в "тоннах" кода строку `var total = Price * paramValuePoroda * ... * paramValueMounting;`, в которой перемножается "вагон" значений. Если вы используете только умножение, то неудивительно, что значения перемножаются. Если вам нужно складывать значения, то используйте для этого сложение.

Comment: @Regent, на ум приходит классическое "Как сложить два числа? - Используйте jQuery!" http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif =)))

Comment: И, конечно, использование `<option value="3.4">29<option>` вместо `<option value="3.4">29</option>` - грустное дело. Хотя бы потому, что из-за этого нельзя автоматически отформатировать ваш HTML-код, а вручную его править - слишком долго.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке:

```
var total = Price * paramValuePoroda * roofValue * paramValueMarch * paramValueNumberSteps * paramValueRailing * paramValueTypeStairs * paramValueTypeTurn * paramValueTypeStage * paramValuePodstupenniki * paramValuePainting * paramValueMounting; //формула расчета общей стоимости
```

вам нужно сложить все после "перил":

```
var total = Price * paramValuePoroda * roofValue * paramValueMarch * paramValueNumberSteps 
    * paramValueRailing + paramValueTypeStairs + paramValueTypeTurn + paramValueTypeStage 
    + paramValuePodstupenniki + paramValuePainting + paramValueMounting;
```

кусочек еще поправить:

```
if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueTypeStairs))
    paramValueTypeStairs = 0;
if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueTypeTurn))
    paramValueTypeTurn = 0;
if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueTypeStage))
    paramValueTypeStage = 0;
if (!$.isNumeric(paramValuePodstupenniki))
    paramValuePodstupenniki = 0;
if (!$.isNumeric(paramValuePainting))
    paramValuePainting = 0;
if (!$.isNumeric(paramValueMounting))
    paramValueMounting = 0;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал как Вы подсказали, этот вариант также почему то неправильно считает http://jsfiddle.net/jL19h58r/ - при вводе в поле Длина лестницы - 1 должно быть 3000, а выдает 3006

Comment: Значения по умолчанию для переменных участвующих в сложении должны быть 0. Добавил в ответ.